# How setup ORYX Build Configuration for Blazor Azure Static Web App

Tags: blazor, github-actions, webassembly, azure-static-web-app, oryx

I have this Github Action for Azure Static Web App for Blazor WASM app and I would like to build my project using Configuration "PROD".
How can I get **oryx** to build the project in **PROD** instead of **Release**?

Thanks!

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "myproject" # App source code path
          #api_location: "Api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "wwwroot" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          action: "close"
```

Comment: Could you update your question to make it more clear (and helpful for others who may come across this) what specifically you are referring to in Azure Static Web Apps with 'Configuration "PROD"'? Is it the Static Web Apps API application settings environment? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings#configure-application-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Just add env variable to your action:

```
env:
  MSBUILD_CONFIGURATION: PROD
```